# Small panel on the side for format editing has vanished?

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I realize that I can edit everything in the .xml files, but I much prefer the layout to the side of the screen when editing details to do with things such as buttons.

My current screen:

[image: my screen]

What it should be like:

[image: what it should be like]

Notice that the second photo has what I'm lacking

I tried doing so, but the Designer button was greyed out, as though I wasn't allowed to use it.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have accidentally removed the Designer tool window. To add it back, on Android Studio 2.1.2 at least, go to View > Tool Windows > Designer, and it should re-appear.

Comment: I tried doing so, but the Designer button was greyed out, as though I wasn't allowed to use it. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: @user24145: Make sure that the Graphical Layout tab is visible when you go and try to toggle on the Designer tool. If that does not help, then I have no idea what could be going wrong. I'm then down to "make sure that you are on the latest Android Studio" or "uninstall and reinstall Android Studio". You could also [file a bug report](http://b.android.com), as I do not see any reports of this behavior.